# Getting Syntax error while executing following query in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to swap the value from m to f, while executing following query, Getting Syntax error

```
UPDATE GenderSET sex = CASE sex WHEN 'm' THEN 'f' ELSE 'm' END
```

Comment: If sex is 'm', you want it to display 'f'?  if it's not 'm' you want to display 'm'??

Comment: I wants vice versa, m to 'f' and f to 'm'

Answer (score 3):

`CASE ... WHEN` is not supported in Access SQL.  You can use an `IIf` expression instead.

```sql
UPDATE Gender SET sex = IIf(sex = 'm', 'f', 'm')
```